# QAbstractVideoSurface file not found

Tags: qt, qt5, qt6

So I've installed `QtMultimedia` and in the picture, you can see all the modules installed.

[image: my components]

Then I added modules to my project's qmake

```
QT += multimedia
QT += multimediawidgets
```

And I can easily use stuff like `QVideoWidget` or `QMediaPlayer` and it compiles. But including `QAbstractVideoSurface` doesn't work!

```
#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>     //file not found
```

I've tried updating components and installing Qt 6.3.0, but the result is the same.

What module did I miss or maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt 6.0.0 and higher versions:

> QAbstractVideoSurface has been replaced by the [QVideoSink](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideosink.html) class, and
> generic rendering support has been enhanced to cover all pixel formats
> supported by Qt Multimedia.

please read [Changes to Qt Multimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html).